# Problema con JavaScipt - ¿Cantidad de paginas?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una pagina como keys.lol desde la primera hasta la ultima llave privada de la Blockchain de Ethereum..

Como todos sabemos, son billones y billones, imposible almacenarlas en algun lado, por lo que se generan a medida que vas saltando de pagina en pagina.

**Pero tengo dos problemas que supongo que van de la mano.**

Hay dos botones, uno para ir a una pagina random, y otro para ir a una llave privada en especifico, ya que como estan en orden, se puede saber en que pagina estaria.

Pero al buscar una llave privada, me deja buscar hasta 13 caracteres, es decir, si busco la llave privada 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000500000000001  la encuentra, en cambio si busco la llave privada 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050500000000001 se queda pensando y no carga nunca, cosa contraria si busco una mas baja, en medio segundo me lleva hasta ella. pero un salto mas y pum no funciona.

Y el boton de random que te tira a una pagina cualquiera, funcionar deberia funcionar pero le pasa lo mismo, se queda pensando y nunca carga, obviamente supongo que es porque me tira a una llave con mas de 14 caracteres.

Entonces no le encuentro logica al problema, necesito un poco de help!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Address Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Address Generator</h1>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search address">
    <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
  </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button id="randomPageButton">Random Page</button>
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Search Private Key">
        <button id="findButton">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <ul id="addressList"></ul>
  <div class="pagination">
    <button id="prevButton">Prev</button>
    <span>Page <span id="currentPage"></span> of <span id="totalPages"></span></span>
    <button id="nextButton">Next</button>
  </div>
  <script src="web3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="buscar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var lastPageSearched = 1;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  function findAddressPage(address) {
    var startIndex = parseInt('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 16);
    var endIndex = parseInt('ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140', 16);
    var pageSize = 100;
    var currentPage = Math.floor((parseInt(address, 16) - startIndex) / pageSize) + 1;
    if (currentPage < 1 || currentPage > Math.ceil((endIndex - startIndex + 1) / pageSize)) {
      return -1; // La dirección no está en ninguna página
    }
    return currentPage;
  }

  // Agregar colores a las direcciones según su saldo de ETH
  function addColorToAddresses(addresses) {
  for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      var publicKey = addresses[i][1];
      web3.eth.getBalance(publicKey, function(error, balance) {
        var color = balance > 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
        var addressElement = document.querySelector(`li[data-address="${publicKey}"] .address`);
        addressElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
      });
    })(i);
  }
}

  document.getElementById('findButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var page = findAddressPage(address);
    if (page >= 1) {
      lastPageSearched = page;
      displayAddresses(lastPageSearched, '');
    } else {
      alert('La dirección no se encontró en ninguna página.');
    }
  });


  function sha3_256(hex) {
    return web3.utils.sha3(hex, { encoding: 'hex' });
  }

  function generateAddresses(start, end) {
    var addresses = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      var privateKey = i.toString(16).padStart(64, '0');
      var publicKey = '0x' + web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + privateKey).address;
      addresses.push([privateKey, publicKey]);
    }
    return addresses;
  }

  var currentPage = 1;
  var addressesPerPage = 100;
  var totalPages = Math.ceil((parseInt('0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140', 16) + 1) / addressesPerPage);
  document.getElementById('totalPages').innerHTML = totalPages;



  function displayAddresses(page, searchTerm) {
    var start = (page - 1) * addressesPerPage + 1;
    var end = start + addressesPerPage - 1;
    if (end > parseInt('0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140 ', 16)) {
      end = parseInt('0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140', 16);
    }
    var addresses = generateAddresses(start, end);
    var addressList = document.getElementById('addressList');
    addressList.innerHTML =
 '';
    for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
      var privateKey = addresses[i][0];
      var publicKey = addresses[i][1];
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(privateKey + ' ' + publicKey));
      if (searchTerm !== '' && publicKey.includes(searchTerm)) {
        li.classList.add('highlight');
      }
      addressList.appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById('currentPage').innerHTML = page;
  }

  displayAddresses(currentPage, '');

  document.getElementById('prevButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      currentPage--;
      displayAddresses(currentPage, document.getElementById('search').value);
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('randomPageButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var randomPage = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalPages) + 1;
  currentPage = randomPage;
  displayAddresses(currentPage, '');
});

  document.getElementById('nextButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (currentPage < totalPages) {
      currentPage++;
      displayAddresses(currentPage, document.getElementById('search').value);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentPage = 1;
    displayAddresses(currentPage, document.getElementById('search').value);
  });

  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      currentPage = 1;
      displayAddresses(currentPage, document.getElementById('search').value);
    }
  });
  const addressList = document.getElementById('addressList');

addresses.forEach(({ address, ether }) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = address;

  if (ether > 0) {
    li.classList.add('hasEth');
  } else {
    li.classList.add('noEth');
  }

  addressList.appendChild(li);
});

});
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de ejecutar el código que publicas y obtengo: `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: addresses is not defined"` Esto ocurre cuando intenta ejecutar el `addresses.forEach()`. Sugiero que completes un [mcve], eso aumentará tus probabilidades de obtener la ayuda que buscas.

Comment: Es una cosa que aun no termine. Es para los colores de los balances, pero no va al caso. Ignoro eso por ahora, el problema esta mas que nada en el id findButton y search. El uqe busca la llave privada y el que salta a una pagina random. Pero como dije, funcionan, solo que no encuentro la logica del porque no mas de 13 caracteres

Comment: Si no es relevante, quítalo de la pregunta. Es decir, alguien tiene que preparar un [mcve] y, sin ánimo de ser pesado, ese no voy a ser yo (no tengo el tiempo para hacerlo). Por eso sugiero que lo hagas tú, pues otras personas en capacidad de ayudarte probablemente tengan tan poco tiempo como yo. Un saludo.